# Guava TreeRow of TreeBasedTable not sorted despite it implements SortedMap?

Tags: java, guava, treetable

Is this by design ?

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> rowMap = treeTable.rowMap();
Map<String, String> notSortedTreeRow = rowMap.get(rowId);
```

so that you can have rowMap sorted (as SortedMap) but you can't have sorted notSortedTreeRow (TreeRow) which is [column, value] ?

EDIT: It was my fault, I had a String representation of Integers and I was on the impression that numerical Strings were compared based on the numerical value :-)

Something like this if I oversimplify it:

```
TreeBasedTable<String, String, String> table = TreeBasedTable.create();

table.put("1", "8", "x");
table.put("1", "9", "x");
table.put("1", "10", "x");

Map<String,String> map = table.rowMap().get("1");
```

Comment: I just don't know how to get TreeRow sorted without allocating new TreeMap for each TreeRow.

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001582/java-sort-a-guava-treebasedtable?rq=1) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do:

```
SortedMap<String, String> sortedRow = (SortedMap<String, String>) rowMap.get(rowId);
```

as it **is** TreeRow object instance, which is SortedMap. It is guarateed by [`RowSortedTable`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/RowSortedTable.html#rowMap%28%29) interface, and it does not override [Table's rowMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v13.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html#rowMap%28%29) argument, because it is not possible in Java.

**EDIT:**

Answering original question here:

> Is this by design?

Yes, it's by Java's design.

Comment: I know it implements SortedMap interface, that's why it is weird that I'm getting unsorted iteration order

Comment: It must be something else then, maybe show the example code with some date you are using.