# Sorting Guava tables in descending order based on values

Tags: java, hashmap, guava

I am planning to use guava tables for storing my values in the table format. I would like to know some function which performs the descending order sorting based on the value in the table ... Could you people throw some views about this. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Sort a Guava TreeBasedTable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001582/java-sort-a-guava-treebasedtable)

Answer (score 6):

Just like with maps, you should copy the `cellSet()`, sort the cells by the values, and then put that into an order-preserving `ImmutableTable`.

```
Ordering<Table.Cell<String, String, Integer>> comparator =
  new Ordering<Table.Cell<String, String, Integer>>() {
    public int compare(
        Table.Cell<String, String, Integer> cell1, 
        Table.Cell<String, String, Integer> cell2) {
      return cell1.getValue().compareTo(cell2.getValue());
  }
};
// That orders cells in increasing order of value, but we want decreasing order...
ImmutableTable.Builder<String, String, Integer>
    sortedBuilder = ImmutableTable.builder(); // preserves insertion order
for (Table.Cell<String, String, Integer> cell :
    comparator.reverse().sortedCopy(table.cellSet())) {
  sortedBuilder.put(cell);
}
return sortedBuilder.build();
```

This is more or less exactly the code you'd write to sort a map by values, anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. If possible could u pls give a glimpse  of this or a link reference