# Timestamp based sorting for a nested Map

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary, timestamp, guava

I have a nested `Map` being returned by the Guava Library's Table structure that is templated as follows:

```
Map<ComplexID1, Map<ComplexID2, MyObject>>
```

where `ComplexID1` is my row key, `ComplexID2` is my column key and `MyObject` holds my metadata. One of the attributes of my metadata is a JODA timestamp.

I need to sort this whole structure chronologically (or reverse chronologically) for display, newest objects created at the top, going backwards.

I was unable to find any information to sort this data structure. Could someone please provide some pointers?

Further, I tried to have the `MyObject` class extend `Comparable` and override `compareTo` on the JODA datetime object because I was trying to use `Collections.Sort()`. Unfortunately, that approach does not seem to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

The solution pointed to below solves the problem perfectly. The code snippet is taken from there. Pasting it here for reference, credit to the original poster (question was under a different title, hence could not find it).

[Sorting Guava tables in descending order based on values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11695949/sorting-guava-tables-in-descending-order-based-on-values)

```
Ordering<Table.Cell<String, FlowId, VersionData>> comparator =
    new Ordering<Table.Cell<String, FlowId, VersionData>>() {
        public int compare(
            Table.Cell<String, FlowId, VersionData> cell1,
            Table.Cell<String, FlowId, VersionData> cell2) {
                return cell1.getValue().compareTo(cell2.getValue());
            }
        };

ImmutableTable.Builder<String, FlowId, VersionData>
    sortedBuilder = ImmutableTable.builder();
    for (Table.Cell<String, FlowId, VersionData> cell :
           comparator.reverse().sortedCopy(tableBackedVersionStore.cellSet()))    
    {
        sortedBuilder.put(cell);
    }
    return sortedBuilder.build();
```

Comment: Vote up! More elegant solution than mine:)

Answer (score 0):

Java8 solution:

```
List l = table.rowMap()
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .flatMap(row -> row.getValue().entrySet().stream()) //Flat row map
        .sorted((col1, col2) -> col2.getValue().compareTo(col1.getValue()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: @Shengyuan Lu - I could understand parts of your answer, but not completely. Could you please elaborate what col1, col2 are with relation to my questions?

Comment: @adwaraki `col1` and `col2` are `Map.Entry<ComplexID2, MyObject>`.